# When Binding<Bool> set in coordinator class, the equivalent binding in parent struct is not being set

Tags: swift, video-player, avplayerviewcontroller

I have the following `VideoPlayerViewRepresentable` struct:

```
enum PlayerItemSource {
    case url(URL)
    case avPlayerItem(AVPlayerItem)
}

struct VideoPlayerViewRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @EnvironmentObject private var videoPlayerEnvironmentObject: VideoPlayerEnvironmentObject

    @Binding var shouldPlayVideo: Bool
    @Binding var didError: Bool
    @Binding var didFinishPlayingVideo: Bool
    @Binding var videoIsFullyLoaded: Bool

    let videoURL: URL
    let playerItemSource: PlayerItemSource?
    // ... more properties

    private let playerItemPublisher = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime)

    static func dismantleUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, coordinator: Coordinator) {
    // ... dismantle
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        var playerItem: AVPlayerItem?

        // ... config logic

        return playerViewController
    }

    private func configureExistingPlayerViewController(existingPlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController, existingPlayer: AVPlayer, context: Context) {
        existingPlayerViewController.player = existingPlayer
        existingPlayerViewController.player?.currentItem?.seek(to: .zero, completionHandler: nil)
        existingPlayerViewController.player?.addObserver(context.coordinator, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayer.currentItem.status), options: [.new, .old], context: nil)
    }

    private func configureThumbnail(videoURL: URL, playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController) {
        let expectedImageIdentifier = "\(videoURL)-\(videoURL)_image"

        if let cachedImage = imageDownloader.imageCache?.image(withIdentifier: expectedImageIdentifier) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let thumbnailImageView = UIImageView(image: cachedImage)
                thumbnailImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                thumbnailImageView.frame = playerViewController.view.bounds
                thumbnailImageView.tag = 1
                playerViewController.view.addSubview(thumbnailImageView)
                playerViewController.view.sendSubviewToBack(thumbnailImageView)
                videoIsFullyLoaded = true
            }
        }
    }

    private func setupContext(_ context: Context, with playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController) {
        context.coordinator.cancellable = playerItemPublisher
            .sink { notification in
                if let playerItem: AVPlayerItem = notification.object as? AVPlayerItem {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if shouldPlayVideo {
                            didFinishPlayingVideo = true
                            playerItem.seek(to: CMTime.zero, completionHandler: nil)
                            playerViewController.player?.play()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }

    private func configurePlayerViewController(playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController, player: AVPlayer, context: Context) {
        playerViewController.delegate = context.coordinator
        context.coordinator.isFullScreenGallery = isFullScreenGallery
        player.addObserver(context.coordinator, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayer.currentItem.status), options: [.new, .old], context: nil)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
        if let player = uiViewController.player {
            if shouldPlayVideo {
                player.play()
            } else {
                player.pause()
            }
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(didError: $didError, videoIsFullyLoaded: $videoIsFullyLoaded, videoURL: videoURL)
    }

    final class Coordinator: NSObject, AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate {
        @Binding private var didError: Bool
        @Binding private var videoIsFullyLoaded: Bool
        private var isVideoReadyToPlay: Bool = false

        var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
        var isFullScreenGallery: Bool = false
        var videoURL: URL

        var timeObserverToken: Any?

        init(didError: Binding<Bool>, videoIsFullyLoaded: Binding<Bool>, videoURL: URL) {
            self._didError = didError
            self._videoIsFullyLoaded = videoIsFullyLoaded
            self.videoURL = videoURL
        }

        func playerViewController(_ playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController, willBeginFullScreenPresentationWithAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
            playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = true
        }

        func playerViewController(_ playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController, willEndFullScreenPresentationWithAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
            coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) { _ in
                playerViewController.player?.play()
            }
        }

        override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
            if keyPath == #keyPath(AVPlayer.currentItem.status) {
                let status: AVPlayerItem.Status

                if let currentStatus = (change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? NSNumber)?.intValue {
                    status = AVPlayerItem.Status(rawValue: currentStatus) ?? .unknown
                } else {
                    status = .unknown
                }

                if status == .failed {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                        guard let self else { return }
                        self.didError = true
                        VideoPlayerStore.sharedInstance.setPlayerURLError(videoURL)
                    }

                } else if status == .readyToPlay {
                    isVideoReadyToPlay = true
                    videoIsFullyLoaded = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We have a couple of bindings in here which should be connected between the coordinator struct and the `VideoPlayerViewRepresentable` class. However, when for example `didError` is set in the coordinator, the changes are not being triggered on the `VideoPlayerViewRepresentable` struct as I would expect them to. For example, if I add a `didSet` to both the `didError` Bool on the `VideoPlayerViewRepresentable` and the equivalent one in the coordinator, the coordinator one gets set but the `VideoPlayerViewRepresentable` does not. Wondering what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out - the didSet will not trigger as the binding itself is not changing, the wrappedValue of that binding is.